# Minted + new environment that can be turned off

Tags: verbatim, minted

I am writing a notebook for some students where I would like to provide optional solutions to coding exercises. I know that, in principle, I can use a custom environment `solutions` that contains code from `minted`. However, I have to be able to turn off this environment when I compile the document, because sometimes exercises have to be blind.

So far, I managed to create a custom environment that can be turned on and off

```
% Define a conditional toggle
\newtoggle{showsolution}
\toggletrue{showsolution} % Initially, show the solutions

% Define a custom environment for solutions
\NewEnviron{solution}{
  \iftoggle{showsolution}
    {\par\textbf{Solution:}\par\BODY}
    {} % Do nothing if \togglefalse{showsolution}
}
```

which I use somewhere in the document as

```
\begin{solution}
This is the solution to a problem bla bla
\end{solution}
```

The problem is that when I include

```
\begin{solution}
\begin{minted}{python}
def hello_world():
    print("Hello, World!")
\end{minted}
\end{solution}
```

I get an error from the verbatim structure of `minted`, precisely `FancyVerb error` with some not-so-clear message output. I have tried wrapping in a `minipage` but could not solve this... has anybody a good solution to this?

Comment: Try the [comment](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package. Its environments can contain verbatim material

Comment: Hi @mbert that is perfect I had no idea about the `comment` package, which I could use to solve this. I post the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the tipi by @mbert I managed to use the `comment` package as follows. The solution also makes use of a `tcolorbox` to wrap the text.

```
\usepackage{comment}

% Define my custom colours 
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{102, 102, 255}
\definecolor{gainsboro}{RGB}{220, 220, 220}

% Define a new tcolorbox environment
\newtcolorbox{solutionbox}{
  colback=gainsboro,
  colframe=darkred,
  title=Solution,
}

\renewenvironment{comment}%
  {\begin{minipage}{1.4\textwidth}%
    \begin{solutionbox}}%
  {\end{solutionbox}%
    \end{minipage}}
```

The solutions can be removed from compilation by commenting out the `\renewenvironment{comment}` instructions.